How to prevent rotation on axis with torsion springs?
I am trying to model a cupholder sizer for a Honda Odyssey, similar to what the Toyota Camry has (example).
I've got a basic design in Fusion360 using torsion springs. What I'm finding though is that the sizer piece (the piece with the circular cutout) is rotating on the axis where the springs are inserted:

What ends up happening is that the sizer rotates till it's vertical, then gets stuck. I think it's probably because it's less force to rotate on the axis than it is to push down the springs.
How can I prevent this rotation and ensure that when downward force is applied (i.e. a water bottle is inserted to the cupholder), it's the springs that are engaged, rather than any other axis of motion?

Can you embed the torsion spring arm in the sizer with a channel? I think your goal is to prevent independent rotation of the sizer and torsion spring arm.

Yep I did exactly that. I also tried staggering them and putting them asymmetric to each other, but they still rotate, now just on a weird skewed axis

Try putting more bends on the torsion spring arm and embed all of that surface into your sizer piece. Either the spring will engage, or the sizer will break.

Maybe a silly question, but if I do more bends, how will I actually insert the spring arm?

Maybe put the pin through the sizer as well? You can do this via hook tabs on the end of the sizer, or an internal slot in the center of the support. This should constrain the rotation to on axis, ie. turn it into a hinge.

That's a great idea, I'll try that! Thanks!
